# Moving a UIView based off of scrollViewDidScroll doesn't work when scrolling too quickly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView that contains some subviews. The UIScrollView takes up the bottom half of the screen, and some other views take up the top half.

Inside of `scrollViewDidScroll`, I check the scroll view's `contentOffset.y` value and when it reaches a certain limit I begin changing the `y` values of the views that take up the top half of the screen. I just increase their `y` values by 1.

If the user begins scrolling back down then I decrease their `y` values by 1.

This works ok, but only when scrolling very slowly. If I do a quick flick/swipe on the scroll view, the views that I am moving no longer move correctly and they get stuck in odd places.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
 - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

if (scrollView == self.bodyContainer && scrollView.contentOffset.y > 19) {

    if (self.lastContentOffsetY < scrollView.contentOffset.y) {

        self.avatar.frame = CGRectMake(self.avatar.frame.origin.x, self.avatar.frame.origin.y - 1, self.avatar.frame.size.width, self.avatar.frame.size.height);
        self.name.frame = CGRectMake(self.name.frame.origin.x, self.name.frame.origin.y - 1, self.name.frame.size.width, self.name.frame.size.height);
        self.username.frame = CGRectMake(self.username.frame.origin.x, self.username.frame.origin.y - 1, self.username.frame.size.width, self.username.frame.size.height);
        self.banner.frame = CGRectMake(self.banner.frame.origin.x, self.banner.frame.origin.y, self.banner.frame.size.width, self.banner.frame.size.height - 1);

        } else {

         self.avatar.frame = CGRectMake(self.avatar.frame.origin.x, self.avatar.frame.origin.y + 1, self.avatar.frame.size.width, self.avatar.frame.size.height);
         self.name.frame = CGRectMake(self.name.frame.origin.x, self.name.frame.origin.y + 1, self.name.frame.size.width, self.name.frame.size.height);
         self.username.frame = CGRectMake(self.username.frame.origin.x, self.username.frame.origin.y + 1, self.username.frame.size.width, self.username.frame.size.height);
         self.banner.frame = CGRectMake(self.banner.frame.origin.x, self.banner.frame.origin.y, self.banner.frame.size.width, self.banner.frame.size.height + 1);
        }
    }

    self.lastContentOffsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
}
```

I am basically trying to accomplish something like the middle screen on this page: http://capptivate.co/2014/03/19/steller-2/